# Facebook's Graph API - Relationship Status Information No Longer Available?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to Facebook's Graph API and I have an app idea that involves using the relationship status field on people's profiles. But it appears that Facebook no longer supports giving out this data because the permissions for it are all deprecated according to this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#extended_perms.

```
user_relationship_details
This permission was deprecated on April 4, 2018.

user_relationships
This permission was deprecated on April 4, 2018.
```

Is there still a way for me to get the relationship status of the individual and their friends?

Comment: Deprecated means it is not possible. If there was a different way they would link to it right there

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#user-4-4 _“Is there still a way for me to get the relationship status of the individual”_ - no. _“and their friends?”_ - and that one, even more no. Users can share almost no data about their friends any more at all; you now need every user you want any info from to login to your app and grant it permissions themself.